# Term for the opposite of the functional Compose operator

Tags: functional-programming, naming, composition

In functional programming, given a function `f` and a function `g` we can define a function `.` (compose):

`let (.) f g = fun x -> g (f x)`

Is there a term for the function which applies arguments in the opposite order? What would be an appropriate term for the `#` operator in the following definition?

`let (#) f g = fun x -> f (g x)`

Comment: Isn't this just `flip (.)`?

Comment: @JörgWMittag yes, that's a way to define it... but "flip compose" isn't a nice name for the function!

Comment: I don't think it has a name. `g ∘ f` is sometimes pronounced ["g after f" or "g following f"](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition), so that would suggest pronouncing `g ♯ f` "g before f" or "f following g". But given that it's really just the same as `∘` with its arguments reversed, I don't think there's a specific name for it.

Comment: Related: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/198575/what-is-the-name-of-%CE%BBx-%CE%BBf-fx-like-reverse-apply-in-lambda-calculus-does-the-c

Comment: One terminology that's in common use for this is distinguishing between *right-to-left* and *left-to-right* composition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a standard name.

Haskell doesn't even bother defining it, but as Jörg said, you can easily define it yourself as

```
flip (.)
```

F# defines it as `>>` and calls it the "forward composition operator."  Scala defines it as the `andThen` method, but doesn't describe it further.  If you looked at 10 more functional languages, you'd probably get 10 different answers.

Unfortunately, functional programming borrowed most of its terms from mathematics, and mathematicians were satisfied with writing function composition "backwards."